# Eloquent has() returning blank relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hey guys I have the following set up;

```
Artist
  id
  name

Album
  id
  name
  artist_id

Release
  id
  name
  album_id
```

I am only wanting to return the Artists, that have Albums, that have Releases

My current query looks like this?

```
/**
 * Helper function returns last artists added
 */
public static function getRecentArtists($limit)
{
    return Artist::where('last_processed', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
           ->whereHas('albums', function($query){
                $query->has('releases');
            })
           ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit($limit)->get();
}
```

However when I check the returned result via;

```
$artists[0]→albums[0]→releases
```

However the collection is empty.

Where am I going wrong? I believed that has() acts as an inner join only returning rows which have related entities?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) directly:

```
return Artist::where('last_processed', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
       ->has('releases')
       ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
       ->limit($limit)
       ->get();
```

And add `releases()` relationship to the `Artist` model:

```
public function releases()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Release', 'App\Album');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breaking this down into segments to see where your query is failing? First start by dumping the result of your first line `Artist::where('last_processed', '!=', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')` then add in the whereHas, and finally, the has() to see if/when it breaks